# move_base alternative

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I was wondering if it exists an alternative(s) to the [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) ?

I have searched but I did not find anything.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318703/move_base-alternative/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2019-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-18**:
Not sure whether it qualifies as an "alternative" for you (as it is more of a refactor), but: [move_base_flex](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_flex)?

It might help board members suggest alternatives if you could describe what it is that you find lacking in `move_base` and/or prompted you to start looking for alternatives.

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-03-18**:
Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes, I have looked at it already. As you mentioned it can be helpful while searching what is lacking in move_base. But what I am searching now is an easy and simple architecture that could be much more optimized than move_base that I can freely add/remove other functionalities.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-18**:\

> Yes, I have looked at it already.

Any reason you did not mention this in your post then? You literally wrote:

> I have searched but I did not find anything.

if you found `move_base_flex` then that cannot be "nothing".

> But what I am searching now is an easy and simple architecture that could be much more optimized than move_base that I can freely add/remove other functionalities.

What would "optimized" be? `move_base_flex` was specifically created to allow people to "freely add/remove other functionalities" by using Action and topic interfaces for everything, instead of compiling everything into a single node.

Could you update your original post with some more information on what you are looking for, what you've tried / already found, why that didn't work for you and what it is that you'd like to see specifically?

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-03-18**:
Thanks a lot for your reply. It is true that I did not explain very well the reason why I searched an alternative for move_base. I will update the question this evening in order to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[locomotor](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/locomotor) is one option.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-03-18**:
Thanks david!